# iOS: Sometimes app is terminated

Tags: ios, crash, terminate

My developing iOS application is **sometimes** terminated after the method `addSubview:` is called in the application delegate (but I'm not sure `removeFromSuperview:` also involved):

```
[self.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];    
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

What that showed in the log is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x019b75a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c41313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x019ad0a5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
    3   <app_name>                          0x000186dd -[TableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] + 205
    4   UIKit                               0x00a742b7 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1834
    5   UIKit                               0x00a71eb1 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRowsInSection:] + 110
    6   UIKit                               0x00b60807 -[UISearchDisplayController _updateNoSearchResultsMessageVisiblity] + 115
    7   Foundation                          0x01029669 _nsnote_callback + 145
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0198f9f9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0190e93a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
    10  Foundation                          0x0101f20e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
    11  UIKit                               0x008df649 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 4581
    12  UIKit                               0x008d9254 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 89
    13  UIKit                               0x008db38f -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 794
    14  UIKit                               0x008d9081 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 252
    15  UIKit                               0x00964dee -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 106
    16  UIKit                               0x00975340 -[UINavigationController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 72
    17  UIKit                               0x008f0e4b -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 918
    18  UIKit                               0x008efa60 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 166
    19  UIKit                               0x008e8750 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1080
    20  UIKit                               0x008e6aa3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 57
    21  <app_name>                          0x00004971 -[AppDelegate requestFinished:] + 993
    22  <app_name>                          0x0003e65b -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] + 171
    23  Foundation                          0x0103e94e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x019988ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x018f688b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x018f5d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x018f5840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x018f5761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x01db11c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x01db1289 GSEventRun + 115
    31  UIKit                               0x008c5c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    32  <app_name>                          0x00002a30 main + 192
    33  <app_name>                          0x00002255 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

How can I find out the reason why the app is terminated by this log and solve it? Thank you.

**Note:** Edit 1 and Edit 2 were removed.

Edit 3: This implemented code of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method works for me:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        if (filteredSectionListOfAddressBook && filteredSectionListOfAddressBook.count)
        {
            return [[filteredSectionListOfAddressBook objectAtIndex:section] count];
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        if (sectionListOfAddressBook && sectionListOfAddressBook.count)
        {
            return [[sectionListOfAddressBook objectAtIndex:section] count];
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your stack trace  - there is a tableview - you need to ensure that there is data to populate the table. Thats where this error is coming from

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

You could for the moment ensure there is no data by making sure that

tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: returns 0;

**Have you implemented the TableViews delegate methods?**

Read about it here [About Table Views in iOS-Based Applications](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=about%20table%20views%20in%20ios-based%20applications&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/&ei=K3DwTp2sE8r28gPMn7SkAQ&usg=AFQjCNEtnZdl4_dFT25hZkcHsV70Oqnopg&sig2=Pwh7XBKYGPclIykmHfHszA)

here [UITableViewDataSource Protocol Reference](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uitableviewdatasource%20protocol%20reference&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html&ei=5HDwToTxH8H18QOt1OzQAQ&usg=AFQjCNEAPxRtWQBq2GIkc_NIWn1mxpXlfw&sig2=qlu6nIiaMhR1qNg4SZ7IOQ)

and here [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uitableviewdelegate%20protocol%20reference&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html&ei=CXHwTv_VJcS-8AOykuW5AQ&usg=AFQjCNHca_68ZTeO4HDBv_faTT0IHVXShg&sig2=pycxGKHXMzGlWBLkO-HudQ)

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. I've tried to make sure that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` not return a number of empty array. My code also includes table view delegate but I don't know which method should I consider? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're right. This error occur because the method `objectAtIndex:` was called on an empty array in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Previous implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in my code did not include checking empty array. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a problem like this in my code, and I found that it was caused by the search delegate holding on to the search bar and the table ref. If a set these properties to nil in searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch then it got rid of the problem. It was likely caused by a circular ref loop. The stack trace looked like so:

[__NSArrayM _updateNoSearchResultsMessageVisiblity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21c350

```
#0 0x3369a1c8 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1 0x338b5aca in -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#2 0x338b4944 in __forwarding__ ()
#3 0x3380f680 in _forwarding_prep_0__ ()
#4 0x30e5aff8 in -[UISearchResultsTableView _numberOfRowsDidChange] ()
#5 0x30d6c3b2 in -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] ()
#6 0x30d6bf4e in -[UITableView reloadData] ()
```